# Problems with Haskell/Hamlet

Tags: html, haskell, functional-programming, hamlet

I'm a beginner at haskell and I'm trying to use hamlet, but I'm no getting the syntax right. When I use this Code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
module Handler.Index where

import Import
import Network.HTTP.Types.Status
import Database.Persist.Postgresql

getIndexR :: Handler Html
getIndexR = defaultLayout $ do
addStylesheet $ StaticR bootstrap_css
[hamlet|
        $doctype 5
        <html>
            <head>

            <body>

        |]

[cassius|
        .classe
            background: red;
        |]
```

I get this error:

```
romefeller:~/workspace/yesodvazio (master) $ stack build && stack exec 
aulahaskell
aulahaskell-0.0.0: build (lib + exe)
Preprocessing library aulahaskell-0.0.0...
[8 of 9] Compiling Handler.Index    ( src/Handler/Index.hs, .stack-
work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.24.2.0/build/Handler/Index.o )

/home/ubuntu/workspace/yesodvazio/src/Handler/Index.hs:18:17: error: parse 
error on input ‘<’

--  While building package aulahaskell-0.0.0 using:
  /home/ubuntu/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-linux/Cabal-
simple_mPHDZzAJ_1.24.2.0_ghc-8.0.2 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-
linux/Cabal-1.24.2.0 build lib:aulahaskell exe:aulahaskell --ghc-options " -
ddump-hi -ddump-to-file"
Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

What am I missing? Do I need to import any librarie or something?

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable:

```
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}
```

instead of `TemplateHaskell` or else GHC tries to parse your `[hamlet|...|]` clause as if it was the start of a list comprehension, like this:

```
[ hamlet | hamlet <- ["alas", "poor", "yorick"] ]
^^^^^^^^^^ -- GHC thinks you're starting to write this
           -- and can't parse the rest.
```

(The `TemplateHaskell` extension *only* enables quasiquote syntax for the specific quasiquote types that it recognizes, and tries to parse everything else as list comprehension syntax.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but now I'm getting an error with the $doctype 5 line:
     /home/ubuntu/workspace/yesodvazio/src/Handler/Index.hs:16:9: 
     error:
     parse error on input ‘$’
     Perhaps you intended to use TemplateHaskell

Comment: I deleted the TemplateHaskell and added the QuasiQuotes line, just like you said, then came an error at the "[hamlet|" and "[cassius|" lines because I forgot using space between the |, and after this, this error that I pasted above showed up

Comment: No, don't add a space before the `|`.  I only showed spaces in my example to show you that Haskell was parsing it as a list comprehension (which is usually written with spaces).  Delete your space -- it must start with `[hamlet| ...`.  Spaces **after** the `|` are fine, but not before.

Comment: If I delete the spaces before it shows these errors:

    /home/ubuntu/workspace/yesodvazio/src/Handler/Index.hs:15:37: 
    error:Variable not in scope: bootstrap_css :: Route Static

    /home/ubuntu/workspace/yesodvazio/src/Handler/Index.hs:16:21: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘WidgetT App IO a0’
                  with actual type ‘t0
                                    -> blaze-markup-0.8.0.0:Text.Blaze.Internal.Markup’

Being the last one repeated at the Cassius line

Comment: Yes, so your problem is solved, and you have other problems:  you've failed to define `bootstrap_css`, for one thing.

Comment: But the boostrap_css error is just one of the problems, there is errors at the [hamlet| and [cassius| lines too

/home/ubuntu/workspace/yesodvazio/src/Handler/Index.hs:15:21: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘WidgetT App IO a0’
                  with actual type ‘t0
                                    -> blaze-markup-0.8.0.0:Text.Blaze.Internal.Markup’

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a code debugging or code writing service, so I don't think anyone is going to be willing to have an extended conversation in the comments to help you fix all the bugs in your code.  Now that you have a new problem unrelated to your old problem, I would suggest that you submit a new question, with an accurate [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the new error messages.